# QTableWidget, incompatibility between background color and padding

Tags: python, pyqt5, padding, background-color, qtablewidget

I would like to create a ‘QTableWidget’ table with two alternating background colors, dark green and light green. The text in the cells must have a left padding of 20 pixels.

```
self.table = QTableWidget(10,3,self)
self.table.setStyleSheet("QTableView{alternate-background-color:rgba(220,254,218,255);background-color:rgba(201,254,198,255);color:rgba(200,0,0,255);font-family:Century725 Cn BT;font-size:12pt;padding:10px;border:2px outset rgba(0,0,126,255);border-radius:30px}QTableWidget::item{padding-left:20px;border:0px}QTableView::item:selected:active{background:#4B94FF;}")
```

When I load the table with a pandas dataframe, the background of the first column is colored with pink.

```
item = QTableWidgetItem(row['Name'])
item.setBackground(QBrush(QColor(255,221,255)))
self.table.setItem(index,0,item)
```

The problem is the following:
I can’t get a pink background color first column and 20 pixels left padding at the same time.
If I get the pink background color of the first column, I don’t have the left padding 20 pixels.
If, on the other hand, I get the 20 pixels left padding, I don’t have the pink background color of the first column.

```
self.table.setStyleSheet("……… QTableWidget::item{padding-left:20px;border:0px} ………") # -> left padding 20 pixels ok!! Nothing background color pink first column
# instead, if I write:
self.table.setStyleSheet("……… QTableWidget::item{padding-left:20px} ………") # -> background color pink first column ok!! Nothing left padding 20 pixels
```

Here is the script in full:

```
#! python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget,QMenu,QTableWidget,QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter,QBrush,QColor,QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt,QPoint
import sys
import pandas as pd


class win(QWidget):

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        super(win,self).__init__(master)
        left=800;top=100;width=1360;height=1200
        self.setGeometry(left,top,width,height)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        self.table = QTableWidget(10,3,self)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Name","Street","City"])
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet('QHeaderView::section{font-family:"Times New Roman";font-size:12pt;color:darkBlue;background-color:rgb(255,239,239);font-weight:400;border:2px solid rgba(0,0,126,255);border-radius:16px}')
        self.table.verticalHeader().setStyleSheet('QHeaderView::section{font-family:"Times New Roman";font-size:9pt;color:darkBlue;background-color:rgb(255,239,239);font-weight:400;border:2px solid rgba(0,0,126,255);border-radius:16px}')
        self.table.verticalHeader().setDefaultAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.table.setStyleSheet("QScrollBar:horizontal{border:2px solid grey;background:#32CC99;height:14px}QScrollBar:vertical{border:2px solid grey;background:#32CC99;width:15px}")
        self.table.verticalHeader().setFixedWidth(35)
        self.table.setColumnWidth(0,300)
        self.table.setColumnWidth(1,300)
        self.table.setColumnWidth(2,300)
        self.table.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.table.setStyleSheet("QTableView{alternate-background-color:rgba(220,254,218,255);background-color:rgba(201,254,198,255);color:rgba(200,0,0,255);font-family:Century725 Cn BT;font-size:12pt;padding:10px;border:2px outset rgba(0,0,126,255);border-radius:30px}QTableWidget::item{padding-left:20px;border:0px}QTableView::item:selected:active{background:#4B94FF;}")
        self.table.setGeometry(200,300,960,400)

        col = ['Name','Street','City']
        data = [['James','Oxford','London'],['Robert','Abbey','Liverpool'],['John','Carnaby','Bristol']]
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col,data=data)

        self.LoadTable(df)


    def LoadTable(self,df):

        self.table.blockSignals(True)
        self.table.setSortingEnabled(False)
        while (self.table.rowCount() > 0):
            self.table.removeRow(0)

        for index,row in df.iterrows():
            self.table.insertRow(index)

            font = QFont('Brush Script MT',20)
            item = QTableWidgetItem(row['Name'])
            item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            item.setFont(font)
            item.setForeground(QBrush(QColor(0,0,255)))
            item.setBackground(QBrush(QColor(255,221,255)))
            self.table.setItem(index,0,item)
            self.table.resizeRowsToContents()

            item = QTableWidgetItem(row['Street'])
            item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignVCenter)
            self.table.setItem(index,1,item)

            item = QTableWidgetItem(row['City'])
            item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignVCenter)
            self.table.setItem(index,2,item)

        self.table.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.table.blockSignals(False)


    def paintEvent(self,ev):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing,True)
        painter.begin(self)
        painter.setBrush(QColor(76,77,0,120))
        painter.drawRoundedRect(self.rect(),140,140)
        painter.end()

    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event):
        delta = QPoint(event.globalPos()-self.oldPos)
        self.move(self.x()+delta.x(),self.y()+delta.y())
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()

    def contextMenuEvent(self,event):
        contextMenu = QMenu(self)
        actionDue = contextMenu.addAction("Exit")
        action = contextMenu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))
        if action == actionDue:
            quit()


App = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = win()
widget.show()
sys.exit(App.exec_())
```

Comment: When using Qt Stylesheets and they define color rules, those rules override almost any aspect of drawing, including those set for item elements. If you want more advanced control, you need to use a custom item delegate. Besides that, some suggestions: 1. for future reference, try to improve your formatting, as your stylesheets are almost impossible to read; 2. using `setStyleSheet()` will ***always*** overwrite (and then invalidate) any previously set stylesheet, so in your case only the last stylesheet will be used for the table; 3. `QPainter(self)` already activates the painter, so you ->

Comment: -> should not call `begin(self)` after that; you also don't need to call `end()`, as the painter will be destroyed at the end of `paintEvent`; 4. when painting with integer based values and geometries, always consider that lines are 1 pixel thick: use `self.rect().adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1)`; 5. avoid fixed geometries, and always prefer [layout managers](://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), otherwise you'll face geometry and displaying issues sooner or later; 6. when creating temporary menus, don't use the parent (`self`) argument. 7. don't use `quit` but `QApplication.quit()`.